# Удаление пустых строк python

Tags: python

Есть файл формата:

```
Number uuid name
1 344235322353432 John

2 432523523423423 Rachel

3 23523123123124 Kody
```

Нужно удалить пустые строки, подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: а как вы их получили?

Comment: Такое может получиться при неправильном использовании модуля `csv`

Answer (score 1):

```
ORIGINAL = "your_file.txt"
EDITED   = "without_blank_lines.txt"

with open(ORIGINAL) as orig, open(EDITED, "w") as edited:
    for line in orig:
        if line.strip():
            edited.write(line)
```

---

*Объяснение:*

- **Читая** очередную строку из вашего оригинального файла (`for line in orig:`)
- **тестируем**, если после удаления всех «пустых» знаков (пробелов, табуляторов, переходов на новую строку) с начала и с конца строки ещё что-то останется (`if line.strip():`)
- и когда да (и только тогда), **записываем** ее в оригинальном виде в выводной файл (`edited.write(line)`).

---

*Замечание:*

Команда `if line.strip():` значит то же самое, как `if line.strip() != "":`

т.к. непустая строка вычисляется как `True` (и пустая как `False`) – см. [Проверка истинности в Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/instrukciya-if-elif-else-proverka-istinnosti-trexmestnoe-vyrazhenie-ifelse.html).

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуемся фильтром на то что строка не является символом перевода строки в лямда-функции, откроем файл с помощью оператора контекста with и представим файл в виде переменной с помощью оператора as:

```py
# in.txt - имя входного файла
# out.txt - имя выходного
with open("in.txt") as a:
    with open("out.txt", 'a') as out: # ключ 'а' показывает, что мы добавляем строки в конец (append)
        for line in filter(lambda x: x != '\n', a):
            out.write(line)
```

Comment: А если не указать `'a'`, то куда допишется строка?

Comment: @user207200 Если не указать 'a', файл по умолчанию откроется на чтение и при попытке его изменить вызовется ошибка. Также есть ключ 'w', что означает, что мы перезаписываем файл (стираем прошлые данные и записываем новые) - полезно, когда мы единоразово записываем что-либо в файл. Подробнее можно почитать здесь http://pythonicway.com/python-fileio

Comment: Ну я это к тому, что скорее всего в данном случае ключ `'a'` не нужен. Один файл на входе - один на выходе. Вообще для таких задач в линуксах лучше использовать консольные утилиты для работы со строками: `sed`, `grep`.

Comment: @user207200, начнём с того, что вопрос именно про Python. Во-вторых, ключ не надо **явно** указывать, если мы читаем файл (не пытаемся его изменить). Если мы хотим изменять файл надо **явно** указать, какой режим мы используем в качестве второго аргумента функции `open`. Это или 'a' или 'w', мне удобнее использовать 'a', т.к. я записываю строки поочерёдно через цикл. Да и попробуйте запустить код без ключа 'a'. Он каждый раз при вызове `write` добавляет строку в конец файла.

Comment: Какая разница через цикл или нет. Зачем плодить путаницу там, где явно создается новый файл.

Comment: @user207200 добавьте свой ответ, который вы будете считать правильным